# Deploying Symfony 4 App to Heroku (PHP Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: APP_ENV environment variable is not defined)

Tags: php, git, symfony, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a symfony app to heroku but after the command "*git push heroku master*" i got this error

> *remote:        Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
>
> remote:        !!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException:
>   APP_ENV environment variable is not defined. You need to define
>   environment variables for configuration or add "symfony/dotenv" as a
>   Composer dependency to load variables from a .env file. in
>   /tmp/build_c283120b0d4ffbcbe11960331dfe8069/bin/console:20
>
> remote:        !!  Stack trace:
>
> remote:        !!  #0 {main} remote:        !!    thrown in
>   /tmp/build_c283120b0d4ffbcbe11960331dfe8069/bin/console on line 20
>   remote:        !! remote:        Script @auto-scripts was called via
>   post-install-cmd remote:  !     WARNING: The APP_ENV environment
>   variable is missing remote:  !     Run 'heroku config:set
>   APP_ENV=prod' to set it.
>
> remote: remote:  !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
>
> remote:  ! remote:  !     The 'composer install' process failed with
>   an error. The cause remote:  !     may be the download or installation
>   of packages, or a pre- or remote:  !     post-install hook (e.g. a
>   'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts') remote:  !     in your
>   'composer.json'.
>
> remote:  ! remote:  !     Typical error cases are out-of-date or
>   missing parts of code, remote:  !     timeouts when making external
>   connections, or memory limits.
>
> remote:  ! remote:  !     Check the above error output closely to
>   determine the cause of remote:  !     the problem, ensure the code
>   you're pushing is functioning remote:  !     properly, and that all
>   local changes are committed correctly.
>
> remote:  ! remote:  !     For more information on builds for PHP on
>   Heroku, refer to remote:  !
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
>
> remote:  ! remote:  !     REMINDER: the following warnings were
>   emitted during the build; remote:  !     check the details above, as
>   they may be related to this error: remote:  !     - The APP_ENV
>   environment variable is missing
>
> remote: remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
>
> remote: remote:  !     Push failed remote: Verifying deploy...*

I changed the line APP_ENV=dev to APP_ENV=prod on .env file but nothing changed... any ideas? How do I add "symfony/dotenv" as a Composer dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear about this:

> You need to define environment variables for configuration or add
>   "symfony/dotenv" as a Composer dependency to load variables from a
>   .env file.

It ain't enough to just create a `.env` file! You must also add `symfony/dotenv` as a composer dependency for symfony to actually use the environment variables defined in the `.env` file.

Run the following command and re-deploy your application to fix your issue:

```
composer require symfony/dotenv
```

Another way to fix the issue is to configure Heroku to provide the `APP_ENV` environment variable when running your application.

```
heroku config:set APP_ENV=prod
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another perspective... Heroku specifically recommends **NOT** using `symfony/dotenv`... so the right answer to this question is simple: you don't.

Practically, using a `.env` file reduces your flexibility, since putting your environment variables in your code means you need to push a new build if you want to change them. And don't forget the fact that you're putting things that are usually supposed to be secrt in your codebase, which is a pretty big no-no from a security perspective ([here's one of many articles on the topic](https://thenextweb.com/dd/2019/03/22/gitlab-now-automatically-warns-against-merging-api-keys-into-your-codebase/)).

Here is Heroku's latest article on the topic, [Deploying Symfony 4 Apps on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-symfony4#environment-variables).  The note at the end of the Environment Variables section says:

> It is recommended that you do not use the `symfony/dotenv` package in
>   production, but instead set all required environment variables
>   explicitly using `heroku config`. Moving `symfony/dotenv` from require
>   to `require-dev` in your `composer.json` will ensure that `.env`
>   files from your application root aren’t picked up in the first place.
>   This corresponds to [option #2 in post-deploy step B of the Symfony
>   documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.3/deployment.html#b-configure-your-environment-variables).

For reference, the linked Symfony docs say this:

> Most Symfony applications read their configuration from environment
>   variables. While developing locally, you'll usually store these in
>   .env and .env.local (for local overrides). On production, you have two
>   options:
>
> 1. Create "real" environment variables. How you set environment variables, depends on your setup: they can be set at the command line,
>      in your Nginx configuration, or via other methods provided by your
>      hosting service.
> 2. Or, create a `.env.local` file just like your local development.

On Heroku, the way to implement #1 is to use Heroku-managed environment variables (either using the CLI or their web interface).